# Javascript loading in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, import, asset-pipeline

I have my javascript imports set up like this in my Rails app:

```
  <script>
    WebFontConfig = {
      google: {
        families: [
          'Open+Sans:300,400:latin'
        ]
      }
    };
  </script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.4.7/webfont.js" />
  <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" />
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

My application.js.erb file is:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require modernizr.custom.44325

//= require jquery-backstretch/jquery.backstretch
//= require infinite-scroll/jquery.infinitescroll

//= require global
```

When I run the app, my fonts load but I get these errors shown in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
>   jquery_ujs.js?body=1:400 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not
>   defined jquery.backstretch.js?body=1:378 Uncaught ReferenceError:
>   jQuery is not defined jquery.infinitescroll.js?body=1:815 Uncaught
>   ReferenceError: $ is not defined

I have tried reordering the imports and depending on the order one of a couple of things happens:

1. Fonts load but nothing else, jquery not defined errors.
2. Page half loads, with javascript and no fonts.

Any ideas on what could be going on? I've not had errors like this before?

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
gem 'pg'
gem "flickraw", "0.9.6"
gem 'kaminari', "0.15.0"
gem 'bourbon'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'sendgrid'
gem 'rdiscount'
gem 'haml'
gem 'slim', '~> 1.3.9'
gem 'naturalsorter', '0.2.2'
gem 'friendly_id'
gem 'awesome_print'
gem 'httparty'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'mechanize'

group :assets do
  gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'
  gem 'sass', github: 'nex3/sass'
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'susy', '2.0.0.beta.3'
  gem 'compass-rails', '>= 1.1.3'
  gem 'compass', '~> 1.0.0.alpha.17'
end

group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
end

group :test do
  gem 'turn', require: false
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'simplecov'
  gem 'spork-rails'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-spork'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

Comment: Can you post your gemfile?

Comment: Is jQuery actually being loaded?

Comment: That's what's weird. By what I have posted above then no, but if I reorder the Google Font, Google Maps and the javascript_include_tag around then my jQuery code will work fine but the font will not.  Any more ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this. It wasn't liking the self closing script tags. Changed them to `<script>` and `</script>` and it's working perfectly now.